# Unhandled Activation Error - Internal Server Error

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to sign in from Visual Studio 2015 Community into my Xamarin Account but I am getting the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at MonoDevelop.Core.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse(CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\ProxySupport\Nuget\RequestHelper.cs:line 141
at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Proxy.VisualStudioWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest, CancellationToken token) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3062\0dd817c0\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\ProxySupport\VisualStudioWebRequestHelper.cs:line 106
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.WebRequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest, CancellationToken token)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.SSO.Client.DoRequest(String endpoint, String method, String body, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.SSO.Client.CreateToken(String email, String password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Xamarin.Components.Ide.SSO.Client.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<CreateTokenAsync>b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I am getting this error both on my Windows PC and Mac. On both there are no updates available. Some version info:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2 - only on the PC
- Xamarin 4.0.3.214
- Xamarin.Android 6.0.3.5
- Xamarin.iOS 9.6.1.8
- Xamarin Studio Community 5.10.3 (build 51) - only on the Mac
- Xamarin.Mac 2.4.2.1 - only on the Mac
- Xamarin build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle6-c6sr3

Do I need to configure some special proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was that I had the `>` and `<` chars in my password. I puzzled about because I had problems signing in at [xamarin.com](https://www.xamarin.com/), but was successful at [auth.xamarin.com](https://auth.xamarin.com/). Now with my new password without those chars I can sign in without problems at both sites.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: I just logged out and back in so Xamarin's side is working)

You need access to *at least* the following for "/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app"

#### From our firewall rules:

```
xamarin.com Port https (443), Protocol TCP
auth.xamarin.com  Port https (443) Protocol TCP
activation.xamarin.com Port https (443) Protocol (CP
software.xamarin.com (107.20.247.61), Port https (443), Protocol TCP 
*.gravatar.com Port https (443), Protocol TCP 
addins.monodevelop.com Port http (80), Protocol TCP
```

`xamarin.com` : Blog page update in the IDE.

`auth.xamarin.com` `activation.xamarin.com`
Are for logging in to your account and/or getting access/auth for `Enterprise` edition.**

`software.xamarin.com` is where updates are checked for and downloaded from .

`*.gravatar.com` add your avatar to the IDE...

`addins.monodevelop.com` is where listings, updates and installs for the IDE Add-In(s) are pulled from.

Note: Nugets are a totally different story. :-/

Note: There are more, but I believe I pulled the critical ones...not that Gravators are critical ;-)

Comment: Being able to open Xamarin's homepage on - say Safari - is an indicator for that it should basically work just fine? I have not installed any firewall on my Mac so I am wondering why it shouldn't be allowed to access those URIs - yet they are just HTTP connections...

Comment: @David Ones like auth.... and activation... are the critical ones for your failure, but yes they "just" secure http connections that are reverse dns to an Amazon's AWS based service... Do you have any proxies set up? Do you have any SSL-based gateways/firewall/routers/accelerators between you and the 'Net. Have you tried from a different network (ISP, coffee shop, home vs work, etc...) You are getting a `500` error, so it is connecting to **something**, the question is it the correct server...

Comment: @david Not necessarily. Opening in the browser is useful as a sanity check, as well as checking status.xamarin.com to make sure the endpoints aren't suffering from downtime. 

However, the error itself is triggered if Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio can't reach those endpoints; they can be blocked by your firewall or other security settings *independently* of whether you can access them in the browser. 

This guide lists all the endpoints commonly used for Activation and other services like the updater: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/firewall/

Comment: @Kent.Green: See my answer.

Comment: My apologies that the solution was quite trivial. Thanks for your detailed info on the outbound endpoints.